# CSS/Bootstrap - Is there anyway to avoid this redundancy?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the font-size based on the view port, for that I am using the below code; however, I feel it's a bit redundant and un-professional. I believe that it should be a better way to achieve the same result.

> P.S. I am using Bootstrap 4

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 500px) {
.block {
 font-size: 5.1em !important;
 }
 } 

@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 800px) {
.block {
 font-size: 6.1em !important;
 }
}

 @media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
.block {
  font-size: 4.8em !important;
}
}

 @media (min-width: 1101px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
 .block {
   font-size: 5.5em !important;
  }
 }

 @media (min-width: 1301px) {
  .block {
  font-size: 6em !important;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a formula behind those font sizes or did you chose them for a certain reason?

Comment: Why not use `vw` or `vh` units - that changes the size of the font based on the viewport (as you can tell by the name of the unit).  But as it looks like your size changes to fit the screen, and these sizes are just random, the only way to do it is the way you are doing it

Comment: Did you know that BS4 already includes [responsive typography](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#responsive-typography)?

Comment: @SalmanA I chosen the font-sizes to change according to the screen size, that the only reason, following this way was the best according to the results I got.

Comment: @ZimSystem I did; however, for some reason it didn't work for me, it seems that it does not even fire up